# Mapping Json Array with Objects as String names (Java)

Tags: java, json, mapping, gson, pojo

I have the json:

```
{
  "albums": [
    {
      "default": {
        "privacy": "public"
           ......
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "second_album": {
        "privacy": "public"
        ......
      }
    },
    {
      "third_album": {
        "privacy": "public"
        ......
      }
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

I want to make Java Objects for this json.

```
public class AlbumsResponse {

     private List<Album> albums = new ArrayList<>();

     public List<Album> getAlbums() {
         return albums;
     }

     public void setAlbums(List<Album> albums) {
         this.albums = albums;
     }
}
```

and

```
public class Album {

    private Title title;

    public Title getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(Title title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

But as you can see Album has no any "Title" field in json but has something like this

```
  "second_album": {
    "privacy": "public"
    ......
  }
```

How to work with this? How to convert name of json-object as unit in json-array to field "title" in java-object?

Comment: You can use the Jackson library https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind

Comment: I don't understand how exactly I can do it. And I need to do it with Gson.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I am not entirely sure how you want to convert the object shown into a `Title`, but I believe that you can achieve what you are looking for with a [custom deserializer](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#custom-serialization-and-deserialization).

For example, the following deserializer takes the first key of the JSON object, wraps this in a `Title`, and then returns an `Album` with that `Title`:

```
public static class AlbumDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Album> {
    @Override
    public Album deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        // Get the key of the first entry of the JSON object
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> firstEntry = jsonObject.entrySet().iterator().next();
        String firstEntryKey = firstEntry.getKey();

        // Create a Title instance using this key as the title
        Title title = new Title();
        title.setTitle(firstEntryKey);

        // Create an Album instance using this Title
        Album album = new Album();
        album.setTitle(title);
        return album;
    }
}
```

You can then register this custom deserializer with your `Gson` instance, and convert your JSON with it:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Album.class, new AlbumDeserializer())
        .create();

AlbumsResponse response = gson.fromJson(json, AlbumsResponse.class);

System.out.println(response);
```

Assuming that your classes implement `toString` in a basic way, running this with your example prints the following:

```
AlbumsResponse{albums=[Album{title=Title{title='default'}}, Album{title=Title{title='second_album'}}, Album{title=Title{title='third_album'}}]}
```